# Helm dependency range failure

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

Take an umbrella chart, umbrella_chart, with one subchart, sub_chart:

umbrella_chart has dependencies defined as follows in it's Chart.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: umbrella_chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes

type: application

version: 0.1.0

appVersion: 0.1.0

dependencies:
  - name: sub_chart
    version: "~0.1.0"
    repository: "@local-development"
```

And sub_chart has a Chart.yaml like:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: sub_chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes

type: application

version: 0.1.0

maintainers:
  - name: Me

appVersion: 0.1.0
```

As part of my CI/CD pipeline, I want to append the Jenkins build number to the sub_chart's version number, before packaging and pushing. This works fine. For build 123 I end up with a version of 0.1.0-123 pushed to local-development.

```
helm search repo --versions --devel
NAME                            CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION                      
local-development/sub_chart       0.1.0-123      0.1.0           A Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

However, when I run `helm dep up umbrella_chart` I get the following error:

```
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "local-development" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Error: can't get a valid version for repositories sub_chart. Try changing the version constraint in Chart.yaml
```

I thought the use of the tilde would allow helm take any chart version >0.1.0 and <0.2.0? Do I need to have a version 0.1.0 of sub_chart in my repo to be able to build umbrella_chart? Will it use the correct 0.1.0-123 version of sub_chart in that instance?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my dependencies were not correctly defined to accept pre-releases, I based my fix on [this](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/issues/1269#issuecomment-632446976).

My new umbrella_chart/Chart.yaml looks like:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: umbrella_chart
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes

type: application

version: 0.1.0

appVersion: 0.1.0

dependencies:
  - name: sub_chart
    version: "~0.1.0-0"
    repository: "@local-development"
```

And it is correctly picking up prereleases.